# Can't run spark shell ! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.mumly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
hadoop@youngv-VirtualBox:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/spark-shell
18/11/30 23:32:38 WARN Utils: Your hostname, youngv-VirtualBox resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
18/11/30 23:32:38 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
18/11/30 23:32:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.mumly(Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$anonfun$$loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:199)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:267)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:247)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:235)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:247)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:282)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

while I want to run the spark-shell, but appear error
with: spark-2.4.0 scala-2.11.12 jdk-1.8 
Anyone could tell me how to solve this problem？ I will be very grateful.

Comment: Hey, you may want to try scala 2.12+ for spark 2.4. It looks like there is a separate package for 2.11: https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/repl/src/main

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.Before I saw your answer, I tried several times but failed, so I reinstalled it and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

there might be different jar version in assembly classpath, remove it and try 
building it again.